# Create a dynamic query for each item in for loop

Tags: apex, query, dynamic-soql, for

Hi I want to create a dynamic query for each item in for loop , but again I don't want to execute that query in the for loop, right now since I am creating a query in for loop, I am no option but executing it in for loop, Is there any better way of doing it?

Any help is appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem statement? You can create Map or Set or List in the loop and use that in the query outside the loop.

Comment: Depends on the complexity of the query. If you used a `map<string,object>` you could store the elements of your query in your map, and use the `object` part to use a inner class to hold more of each query. The tricky part would be merging the say two different queries to the same sobject